# How to display image from server on react native?

Tags: react-native

I just started a react native project and want to display images. Urls of images come from the server side and I want to display them, but images are not displaying.

I am storing an image URL into a variable then pass this variable to require.

```
    //responseJson.url = "https://localhost.com/content/img/react_thumb_install.png";
    const imgUrl = responseJson.url;
    <Image source={imgUrl} />
```

How could I display the image directly from the server?

Comment: check the data type of responseJson.url and convert to string. Also, try with `URI` or `required`

Comment: Hi vivek, I tried but still not working. Is there any alternate way?

Comment: <Image source={{ uri: Image_Http_URL }} />

Comment: I have posted an answer you can check there.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass uri option like below since it's you want to load it from a url:

```
<Image source={{uri: imgUrl}}
       style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
```

See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#network-images for more details

Comment: @ user11789850 Corrected the answer. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is how you can display the image which is coming from Server

<Image 
     source={{uri:'https://snack.expo.io/web-player/37/static/media/react-native-logo.2e38e3ef.png'}}
      style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
/>


// -----------------------------------------
// This is how you can display the image which is coming from your local folder

<Image 
  source={require('../assets/images/app-logo.png')} 
  style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
 />
```

Answer (score -1):

Go through : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images

```
 <Image 
     source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
      style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
```

The data passed is incorrect, it understand javascript object not the string you are passing the string variable. Check with passing

```
<Image 
 source={{uri: imgUrl}}
  style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
```

Comment: hi, I am passing a variable not string url. When I use url it is showing but when I pass variable its not working.

Comment: @BabluGaur you are passing <Image source={imgUrl} /> where it won't understand imgUrl, you need to pass the data as {{ uri: imgUrl }}